# Difference between deep neural network and convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wanted to develop an app similar to [this](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/) on my own which is based on image classification using neural nets. While in early phases of my research I came across through terms **Deep Neural Nets** and **Convolutional Neural Nets**.

What is the difference between two and which will be the best bet for me to work on for this project?

Edit1:- I looked on kaggle's digit recogniser for my initial research

Comment: [DNN](https://www.kaggle.com/kakauandme/digit-recognizer/tensorflow-deep-nn) and [CNN](https://www.kaggle.com/kobakhit/digit-recognizer/digit-recognizer-in-python-using-cnn)

Comment: I can't add more than two links. I'm short of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The term deep neural nets refers to any neural network with several hidden layers. Convolutional neural nets are a specific type of deep neural net which are especially useful for image recognition. Specifically, convolutional neural nets use convolutional and pooling layers, which reflect the translation-invariant nature of most images. For your problem, CNNs would work better than generic DNNs since they implicitly capture the structure of images.

If you want a good layman's introduction to deep learning and CNNs, there's a great Nature paper (if you search "deep learning nature" on Google, it's one of the top links).

Comment: Does that mean I can use both .?

Comment: You can use either a generic DNN or a CNN, but a CNN will almost certainly give you better results. You should start out with implementing a DNN though, since it's easier and you'll gain some knowledge and intuition about neural networks.